# Add static Realm.framework but compile with error: framework not found Realm clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, realm

I add the static Realm.framework as the document describe:

1、Download the latest release of Realm and extract the zip.
2、Drag Realm.framework from the ios/static/ directory to the File Navigator of your Xcode project. Make sure Copy items if needed is selected and click Finish.
3、Click on your project in the Xcode File Navigator. Select your app’s target and go to the Build Phases tab. Under Link Binary with Libraries click + and add libc++.tbd.
4、If using Realm with Swift, drag the file at Swift/RLMSupport.swift into the File Navigator of your Xcode project, checking the Copy items if needed checkbox.

Objective-C, Xcode 7.3. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check your Framework Search Path. If there is no path defined, try to add path.

Comment: Have added Framework Search Path, same error message

Comment: First try this : 
1. Go to your project target setting page
2. Click the "Build Settings" tab
3. Search "Bitcode"
4. Set "Enable Bitcode" to "No"

then clean-> build -> run.

Comment: if this not work try this.

I know this is odd way. But can you try this :
1. Remove all framework references from Xcode.
2. Remove framework from Framework directory if exist.
3. Close Xcode.
4. Drag and drop your framework into Framework Folder in Project navigation.
5. check path for same.

then clean-> build -> run.

Comment: And even try to run directly on device.